# how do i use a button to move a range of cell contents to another range in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Every day I run a query that replaces data in an Excel workbook on Sheet1. Sheet2 is a report that uses formulas to summarize the new data on Sheet1. I need to start trending the report data on Sheet3. I want to put a button on Sheet2 that I can click that will move data from C20:N20 on Sheet2 and store it in the next available row in columns B:M on Sheet3. I know I could just record a macro and grab that code and assign it to the button, but I can't figure out how to tell the code to look for the next available row.

This is wrong, but represents what I'm trying to do, how do I fix it?

```
Sub Apv_Conv_TrendIt()
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1: Sheets("Sheet3").Range("M1000000").End(xlUp).Row 1
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & LastRow) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C20:N20")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of copy/paste, try a *Value Transfer*

```
Sub Move()

Dim cRange As Range, LR As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    LR = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Set cRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C20:N20")
    .Range(.Cells(LR, "B"), .Cells(LR, "M")).Value = cRange.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: was about to paste similar, though i feel that setting the range to use the range is wasteful, given this is a single line occurrence... *.Range(.Cells(LR, "B"), .Cells(LR, "M")).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C20:N20")*

Comment: @Cyril def a valid statement. I started typing it out with intent to copy paste and then changed my mind and didn’t go back

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question. Keep is simple

Create a Button on sheet2

Assign a new macro to the button and place this single line of code between the Sub and End Sub

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C20:N20").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are kinds of ways to do this.  Here's one option.

```
Sub CopyRange()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D20").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Now, if the ranges will change dynamically, you would want to do it more like this.

```
Sub SelectFilledCells()
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
End Sub
```

Take a look at these links as well.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/assign-button-macro/